# How to hide text selection tool menu in double click?

Tags: android, textview, onclicklistener, copy-paste, textselection

We know that `setTextIsSelectable()` is used to select the text.So when we long press the text selection tool menu appear (copy/paste menu).

If we double click on the textview also the menu option appear.

I would like to know how to hide the menu in double click ?

NB:I need the text is always selectable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When text is selectable android will show the text selection menu in double tap.To disable this problem we need to implement **GestureDetector**
with **onTouch**. Then in the GestureListener set **setTextIsSelectable(true)** in **onLongPress** and **setTextIsSelectable(false)** in **double tap**.

Comment: could you help me this solution with code? Thanks in advance

Answer (score -1):

Here is what you have to do:

> **setTextIsSelectable**
>
> When you call this method to set the value of `textIsSelectable`, it
>   sets the flags `focusable`, `focusableInTouchMode`, `clickable`, and
>   `longClickable` to **the same value**. These flags correspond to the
>   attributes `android:focusable`, `android:focusableInTouchMode`,
>   `android:clickable`, and `android:longClickable`. **To restore any of these
>   flags to a state you had set previously, call one or more of the
>   following methods**: `setFocusable()`, `setFocusableInTouchMode()`,
>   `setClickable()` or `setLongClickable()`.

Source: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#setTextIsSelectable(boolean)